# Get the latest state of a row in MySQL

Tags: mysql, aggregate-functions

I have a very weird thing to do and simply don't know how. This is my table and its data:

```
+------+-----------+-------------+-------+------------+
| uid  | entity_id | entity_type | state | created    |
+------+-----------+-------------+-------+------------+
| 3913 |      1105 |           1 |     0 | 1340617072 |
| 3913 |      1105 |           1 |     1 | 1340617042 |
| 3913 |      3930 |           1 |     0 | 1340617071 |
| 3913 |      3930 |           1 |     1 | 1340617036 |
+------+-----------+-------------+-------+------------+
```

`created` holds the timestamp for which an action has been made, `state` is the state of the action (followed or unfollowed), `uid` is who makes the action and `entity_id` is the entity ID which is being followed/unfollowed.

I'm trying to do a query which gets me all the `entity_id` which the current user follows. First I was using:

```
SELECT entity_id FROM follow_objects WHERE uid=? AND entity_type=?
```

However I noticed that if I follow someone and then unfollow them, I still get a result for that person, because there are 2 entries for it (with state=1 and then state=0).

So I need to get the rows with the newest `created` column, which means the action is the most recent one. So I've tried:

```
SELECT entity_id FROM follow_objects WHERE uid=? AND entity_type=? group by entity_id HAVING created=MAX(created)
```

Which returns only rubbish data. I'm out of ideas. Any help?

Comment: `...ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT 1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to select on a *group-wise maximum*. You must wrap the maximum in a subselect and join the table on itself where the `entity_id`s are equal and where the subselect's max timestamp equals the created timestamp. The result is that you'll get the top row data per `entity_id` group:

```
SELECT
    a.entity_id,
    b.state,
    b.created
FROM
    (
        SELECT entity_id, MAX(created) AS max_created
        FROM follow_objects
        WHERE uid = ? AND entity_type = ?
        GROUP BY entity_id
    ) a
INNER JOIN
    follow_objects b ON
        a.entity_id = b.entity_id AND
        a.max_created = b.created
```

Comment: You, my Sir, are a God! Worked without any changes. I would have wanted to do sub-queries/JOINs because I have to run this query 4 times in a stored procedure, but since it's a valid solution, I'm going to put it up. Thanks!

Comment: You might want to compare mine for speed. Mine should be an order of magnitude faster, since it only does one pass over the table and involves no joins

Comment: @EduardLuca, I added two fields to the `SELECT` clause because if all you're doing is selecting `entity_id`, and you don't need its associated data, then you could just use the subselect by itself... even without the `MAX()`.

Comment: I'm only interested in the one column from the big query, but I couldn't get the inner query return the correct results, but it's not important, cause I found a workaround which lets me only run this query once per stored procedure which is totally acceptable (as the query runs in less than 0.01s). @off-topic: Got myself a SP that runs in 0.05s (from 0.1s before), yaay!

Answer (score 0):

Select all matching rows first and order them by created date (latest first), then from that result, take the first one:

```
SELECT entity_id
FROM (
    select entity_id, created
    from follow_objects
    WHERE uid=?
    AND entity_type=?
    order by created desc
) x
limit 1
```

Easy to understand and code.

fyi, the "x" after the bracket is there because you need to give an alias to all result sets selected from, so I called it "x".

Comment: The `LIMIT 1` in your solution will only retrieve the `entity_id` with the latest `created` timestamp overall. There could be multiple differing `entity_id`s where `uid=? AND entity_type=?`, and the OP wants the latest row data associated with ***each*** entity_id that satisfy those conditions.